# Prove that $\angle IPA=\angle IQB$ in $\triangle ABC$ with incenter $I$.

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

### Problem

In $\triangle ABC$, $AB<BC$ and its incenter is $I$. $P$ is the midpoint of $AC$ and $Q$ is the the midpoint of arc ${ABC}$. Prove that $\angle IPA=\angle IQB$.

The problem is from a monthly Olympiad training contest. I am not able complete my solution. Here are my workings.

### My workings

Here is the figure of my incomplete solution:
[image: Solution figure]
Since $Q$ is the midpoint of arc $ABC$, $\triangle AQC$ is isosceles with $AQ=CQ$. $PQ$ is the perpendicular bisector of chord $AC$. $PQ$ is extended to $R$ such that $R$ is the intersection point with the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$. Then $QR$ is the diameter of the circle. So, $\triangle ARC$ is also isosceles with $AR=CR$.
Then I can't proceed further. I can not bring $I$ in the solution. Though it is easy to see that $B,I,R$ are collinear from the figure. But I cannot prove that. And how to use it in the rest of the solution?

---

So, I need to complete my solution with proper proof.

Comment: You should somehow exploit that $BI$ is the bisector of $\angle ABC$ (that's why $R$ lies on $BI$), and an analogous property holds for $AI$ and $CI$.

Comment: Drop a perpendicular from I to AC then prove that triangle IXP is similar to IBQ.

Comment: You can use that $RP\cdot RQ=RI^2$.

Comment: @richrow How did you get that, and how is that of any use? Sorry if I'm not being smart enough

Comment: @husnucuk Then, triangles $RIP$ and $RQI$ are similar and we can get some equalitites for angles of these triangles.

Comment: @richrow but how did you initially get that equation?

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trillium_theorem and note that the triangle $RAQ$ is right-angled and $AP\perp RQ$.

Comment: @richrow Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By [Euclid's theorem of altitude](https://www.geogebra.org/m/tUYgVpRT) ($AR^2=RP \cdot RQ$) and by [the Incenter-Excenter Lemma](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/Fact5/Fact5.pdf) $(AR=IR)$ we get (as already hinted by @richrow):

$$RP\cdot RQ=RI^2 \implies \triangle RIP \sim \triangle RQI$$

Hence:

$$ \angle RIQ=\angle RPI \implies \angle BIQ=\angle QPI$$

Now, noticing that $\angle QBR=90°$ and $\angle APR=90°$:

$$\angle IPA=\angle IQB \;\;\;\; \blacksquare$$